# How can I incorporate changes of other branch into the current branch if the current branch not finished yet?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches, they both were created off the master. The 1st one is half-ready, the 2nd one is ready and has been merged into master.

The 1st branch has begun dependent on the new functionality of the 2nd branch. What's the recommended and clean way of incorporating the new functionality of the 2nd branch -- that's already in master -- to the 1st one?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to just merge or rebase the first branch with the `master` branch:

```
# from first branch
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

or

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

This should be acceptable assuming that you don't mind potentially bringing in changes *other* than the second branch, which are now in the `master` branch.

Comment: This is just a detail, but you might want to make explicit in the answer that the `git fetch origin` command is also needed for the `git rebase origin/master` alternative.